# Hibernate orphanRemoval removes all rows and then inserts rows

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Following example is simplified.

I have following database structure:

```
X
 -xid VARCHAR

Y
 -yid VARCHAR
 -xid VARCHAR
 -zid VARCHAR
Z
 -zid VARCHAR
```

I have following Entity structure

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "X")
public class EntityX {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "xid")
    private String xid;

    @OneToMany(... mappedBy = "x", cascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<EntityY> yList = new ArrayList();
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Y")
public class EntityY {  
    @Id
    @Column(name = "yid")
    private String yid;

    @ManyToOne(cascadeType.ALL)
    private x;

    @ManyToOne(cascadeType.ALL)
    private z;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Z")
public class EntityZ {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "zid")
    private String zid;
}
```

My save method is:

```
X x = new X();
x.setXid(1);

Z z = new Z();
z.setZid(1);

Z z2 = new Z();
z2.setZid(2);

Y y = new Y();
y.setYid(1);
y.setX(x);
y.setZ(z);

Y y2 = new Y();
y2.setYid(2);
y2.setX(x);
y2.setZ(z2);

List<Y> yList = new ArrayList<Y>();
yList.add(y);
yList.add(y2);
x.setYList(yList);

entityManager.persist(x);
```

The save is working perfectly and sqls are:

```
insert into X (XID) values (1);
insert into Z (ZID) values (1);
insert into Y (YID, XID, ZID) values (1, 1, 1);
insert into Z (ZID) values (2);
insert into Y (YID, XID, ZID) values (2, 1, 2);
```

My update method is:

```
X x = new X();
x.setXid(1);

Z z = new Z();
z.setZid(1);

Z z3 = new Z();
z3.setZid(3);

Y y = new Y();
y.setYid(1);
y.setX(x);
y.setZ(z);

Y y3 = new Y();
y3.setYid(3);
y3.setX(x);
y3.setZ(z3);

List<Y> yList = new ArrayList<Y>();
yList.add(y);
yList.add(y3);
x.setYList(yList);

entityManager.merge(x);
```

The update does following sqls:

```
insert into Z (ZID) values (3);
insert into Y (YID, XID, ZID) values (3, 1, 3);

delete from Y where XID=1; Why?
delete from Z where XID=1; Why?
delete from Y where XID=2;
delete from Z where XID=2;

insert into Z (ZID) values (1); Why?
insert into Y (YID, XID, ZID) values (1, 1, 1); Why?
```

Why Y (`YID=1`) and Z (`ZID=1`) are deleted and after they are inserted? This is a performance problem if there are for example 100000 times Y and Z which are not changed.

Answer (score 2):

When you are trying to update, do not try to create the entity manually again and perform the merge. You end up having problems when you have cascading options set on your related entities like above.

During the merge, the persistence context retrieves the x(xid=1) entity along with the OneToMany list. You newly created X entity though has a new instance of list. Now persistence provider takes under consideration the `orphanRemoval` flag and decides that the previous state is not valid any removes all the content of Y with xid=1 (as they are not present in the new list).

Then it inserts the newly added elements in the new List.

I would recommend fetching the X with xid=1 first and then performing the update on a persistence-context managed entity:

```
X x = session.get(X.class, 1);
...

List<Y> yList = x.getYList();
yList.add(y);
yList.add(y3);

entityManager.merge(x);
```

all within one transactional method.

Comment: How the Hibernate works? The save method saves the data to the database. How the Hibernate can know that what is "newly created X". Is it using the Cache? I tried to use the flush, but it didn't help.

Comment: It uses proxy objects and also checks whether a certain object is in the persistence context (kind of a single session cache). Flush wont do much help here. Again, your best bet is to retrieve the entity before updating it.. not creating it from scratch all the time

Comment: I think this complicates logic when entity and its children are updated. When children are deleted you have to detect manually which children are deleted. I hoped that Hibernate would do the job for me.

Comment: I have one example where are not enties EntityZ and there orphanRemoval works perfectly. There entity EntityX is not retrieved before the update.

Comment: Im not saying this will never work.. its just not the advisable way especailly with those cascading ooptions  set.

Comment: Is there any JPA specification or a Hibernate user guide, which says that an entity (and children) is good to retrieve before the update.

Comment: This way or a batch update are the only paths I stumbled upon in my career, batch update being a rare case on top of that. Merge in general is for making the entity managed again, after it has been detached from the persistence context. Also, why to recreate manually the entity if you have the id and fetch all its content from db. Also you can miss out some field and unintentionally clear the column in the database.